# Unity3d GUI.Button text change within hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, hierarchy

Here is the entire class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class HierarchyPlus{

    static HierarchyPlus()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HierarchyItemCB;
    }

    private static void HierarchyItemCB(int instanceID, Rect selectionRect)
    {
        GameObject go = (GameObject)EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID);
        Rect rect = new Rect(selectionRect);
        rect.x = rect.width - 30;
        string btnStr = "On";
        if (go != null)
        {
            GUI.skin.button.fixedWidth = 30;

            if (GUI.Button(rect, btnStr))
            {
                Debug.Log(go.name);
                if (go.activeSelf == true)
                {
                    go.SetActive(false);
                    btnStr = "Off";
                }
                else
                {
                    go.SetActive(true);
                    btnStr = "On";
                }
            }
        }               
    }    

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I want to change the GUI.Button text which i draw onto the hierarchy item. The activation and deactivation of the GameObjects works only the Button text doesnt change, it stays as "On".

Edit 1// added the full class and reformulated my issue

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What's not working?

Comment: The gui.button text doesnt change, it just stays as On, but the gameobject dis/ and reactivation works

Comment: Post more code. Add the whole class if possible.

Comment: added the full class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `string btnStr = "On";` in the `HierarchyItemCB` function.

The `btnStr` variable is being re-initialized to `"On"` each time the `HierarchyItemCB` function is called.

Declare and initialize the `btnStr` variable outside the `HierarchyItemCB` function. Also mark it as `static` so that you can access it in the `HierarchyItemCB` function is also a `static` function.

---

**EDIT**:

This is tricky since `HierarchyPlus` **must** be a static function. A solution is to use a Dictionary. Use the `instanceID` as the key and the button `string` as the value.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class HierarchyPlus
{

    static HierarchyPlus()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HierarchyItemCB;
    }

    static Dictionary<int, string> instanceToBtnStr = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    private static void HierarchyItemCB(int instanceID, Rect selectionRect)
    {
        Debug.Log("Over");


        GameObject go = (GameObject)EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID);
        Rect rect = new Rect(selectionRect);
        rect.x = rect.width - 30;


        if (go != null)
        {
            //Add key if it is not in the Dictionary yet
            if (!instanceToBtnStr.ContainsKey(instanceID))
            {
                //Add with Default On Key
                instanceToBtnStr.Add(instanceID, go.activeSelf ? "On" : "Off");
            }

            GUI.skin.button.fixedWidth = 30;

            //Initialize btnStr from Dictionary
            string btnStr = instanceToBtnStr[instanceID];

            if (GUI.Button(rect, btnStr))
            {
                Debug.Log(go.name);
                if (go.activeSelf == true)
                {
                    go.SetActive(false);
                    instanceToBtnStr[instanceID] = "Off";
                }
                else
                {
                    go.SetActive(true);
                    instanceToBtnStr[instanceID] = "On";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: thx that solved it and i should have seen it myself, nevertheless does this change the text of every gui.button for every hierarchy item, not just the one clicked.

Comment: But the HierarchyPlus() function needs to be static, else it doesnt seem to work and if that function is static HierarchyItemCB also must be static, or not?

Comment: it doesnt work, would be nice if u could test it on ur computer when it fits ur time schedule :D

Comment: I want to draw buttons on each of the hierarchy items and deactivate the according gameobject via click on this button(whick works) i only needed to get the text change for the clicked button working.

Comment: thx alot, idk why it didnt work b4, i created a new script and now it worked, once again, thx for taking the time :D